I mentioned a sibling residing in UK in my UK visitor visa application, but she's not a sponsor. Should I still upload a digital copy of her passport?
I am applying for a UK Standard Visitor visa. In my application form, I mentioned that I have a sibling who resides in UK on a temporary basis. So, I provided her passport number in the corresponding field. However, she's not sponsoring my trip. In this case, do I still need to submit a digital copy of her passport even if it's not mentioned in the document checklist?
Thanks in advance

Do the instructions tell you to upload passports of relatives who are not sponsors?

@DJClayworth: No, at least they don't explicitly tell me to do so. But the checklist provides fields for other documents where I can put down the name or description of additional documents.
